# Change RMI port on Websphere 6 using Maximo

Tags: websphere, maximo

**The set up**

I have websphere 6.1 running two application servers. Each running the same application (Maximo). Each application point to a different database.

There is a third party app that connects VIA an RMI port of 13400.

Both Maximo applications have this in the proprieties file.

```
mxe.registry.port=13400
```

**The issue**

When the third party program makes a call to the RMI port the wrong application processes gets the call.

**What I have tried**

I can't find anything in the WebSphere console that would let me change the port.

Changing the RMI port in the Maximo properties file to 13400 and redeploying the ear. Then changed the port on the third party software. No dice. In fact I get a Error 500 System not bound on when accessing Maximo.

```
ServletWrappe E   SRVE0100E: Did not realize  init() exception thrown by servlet ReportBridgeServlet: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.tivoli.maximo.report.birt.logging.ReportLoggerFactory
at com.ibm.tivoli.maximo.report.birt.bridge.launcher.FrameworkLauncher.<init>(FrameworkLauncher.java:83)
at com.ibm.tivoli.maximo.report.birt.servlet.MXWebAppOSGiFrameworkLauncher.<init>(MXWebAppOSGiFrameworkLauncher.java:33)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1328)
    ...... 12000++ lines of errors like this one.
```

As ring bearer pointed out this error doesn't correlate with changing the RMI port. Yet when I change the proprieties file back to 13400 there are no error what so ever.

**The Question**

How do I change the RMI port for each application server?

**Hypothesis**

I'm hoping it's somewhere in the application server.

Comment: is the Maximo application reading this value: mxe.registry.port=13400? What does it do with it? Does it start sockets listening on this port, or start an RMI registry of its own? If it does, that explains your odd behavior if you set it to 5021. It's clashing with the BOOTSTRAP port of WAS.

Comment: The RMI registry is started by the first instance of the maximo application to run. A WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment environment could have multiple instances of the product application running at one time. This registry coordinates these instances. There is a single central RMI registry server. This is the port available for the other application instances to communicate with the central server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found what I was looking for:

In the maximo.properties file add this...

```
// Port used by RMI for communication, if left at 0, RMI will use any available
// port on the system. To use a specific port, set this parameter to an available  
// port number.
mxe.rmi.port=0
```

I set it to 12222 rebuilt the ear and redeployed. Port 12222 never opened up.

The real issue was the mxe.name all there applications had the same name in the proprieties file. Changing the names resolved the issue.

```
// Name to bind the MXServer server object to in the RMI registry
mxe.name=MXServer
```

https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21262022

Answer (score 0):

Logon to admin console and follow this selection path - Application_servers > server1  > Ports > BOOTSTRAP_ADDRESS

Note that once you are on the "Server1" selection page, the ports link will appear on the right hand side, under "Communications" section

Assuming your default server name is server1
You will have a screen where you can edit port number for BOOTSTRAP_ADDRESS- which is the WebSphere Application Server name Service or RMI Connector Port.

Comment: Hmm... things don't line up. The port in the properties file and the third party app is 13400. Netstat shows 13400 open. All the ports listed under ports for the app server are in the 5000 - 9000 range for both application servers.

Comment: OK - based on your question - Your server is showing ports 5000 - 9000 and third-party app is looking up some other port. I was under the impression that you were trying to edit Websphere settings so that the RMI port matches what the third-party is looking up. Now, to further troubleshoot, please post the errors that you are getting  - or elaborate on your "The issue" section.

Comment: Hi, Your log shows that you have some other issues, it does not show anything regarding this port issue you are mentioning. As long as changing Websphere RMI port goes my answer still holds. You have `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` which needs more detailed description about your app set up to troubleshoot - thanks!

Comment: That's one of the reasons I asked the question (the log files don't seam to correlate with the actual issue). If change the port in the properties file back to 13400 the application never throws an error.

Comment: The BOOTSTRAP_ADDRESS on the app is 5021 yet the third party app connects on 13400. Your answer makes sense... it just doesn't fit what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of your weblogic folder and rename it something else. You can change the settings on the second instance.